# how to exclude an element using CSS3?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is the code:

```
input:not(#radioo input){
    display: block; 
    font-size:23px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    width:310px;
    height: 40px
}
```

but all `input` are excluded! and I want only to exclude `input` that is in the `form` that has the `ID` `radioo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following selector seems to do what you want.  Only the input in the second form will have an orange background.

http://jsfiddle.net/pYhgr/

```
form:not(#radioo) input {
    background: orange;
}

<form id="radioo">
    <input type="text" />
</form>

<form>
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: it is bizarre, but it dont work, Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m

Comment: Odd.  I have Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m and the fiddle works for me.  Also works in Opera (12.14) and Firefox (18.0.2).

Comment: Not much I can do about that, I guess.  Musa's original answer didn't have the correct selector until after my answer was posted (which was a few seconds after Gumbo's comment).

Answer (score 3):

`:not` only takes [`simple selectors`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) the best solution would be to give each input you want to exclude a class and use `:not(.theclass)`

From the comments it seems there is a solution without adding a class

```
form:not(#radioo) input{
    display: block; 
    font-size:23px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    width:310px;
    height: 40px
}
```

Comment: @Gumbo: That would easily match the parent of `input` assuming the parent isn't `form#radioo` since you're not supposed to have an `input` directly inside a `form` in valid HTML. Using `:not()` with descendant selectors is generally not reliable.

Comment: @Musa it dident work i dont know why! i use Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m

Comment: Update: it worked, i ommited the space before input, dident know that i must let a space :p

Comment: @BoltClock You’re right. `*:not(#radioo)` it would match *any* parent element that doesn’t have the ID “radio”. But since an `input` can only have one parent `form`, the `form` instead of `*` is necessary.